# How To add route::parseExtension to particular action in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

In cakephp Route::parseExtension("csv"); enables the extensions on each and every action but i want to apply on particular action is it possible.

Comment: Got the solution.Add the `code`Router::parseExtensions('csv');`code` to router.php and Just create separate controller and add RequestHandler component to controller component array. ParseExtension only works when the Requesthandler component is enabled in the controllers component array.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution: add the `Router::parseExtensions('csv');` to `router.php`, create a separate controller and add the `RequestHandler` component to controller component array. `ParseExtension` only works when the `Requesthandler` component is enabled in the controllers component array.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
Router::parseExtensions('csv');
Router::connect('/some_alias', array('controller' => 'your_controller', 'action' => 'your_action'));
```